# Swelling delay?

Tags: guitar-effects, effects-pedal

I was watching Steven Wilson's DVD "Get All You Deserve" and was wondering how to create a particular guitar effect. At the end of the song "Raider II," the band is jamming slowly as each member eventually walks off stage.  Guitarist Niko Tsonev is using an effect where he plays a fast riff, and as he plays, the notes seem to collect and swell/fade in a delay I have never heard before. The effect is not echoing each note he plays as he plays it, but rather mashing them all together and swelling them up and out almost a second after they are played.

Here is the link:

The song is almost 24 minutes long, and a great tune! But if you want to get to where I am referencing, go to about the 21:48 mark. The sound quality is not that great, so headphones may be required. You also have to listen through the flute that is playing as well.

Please help! I am exhausting myself over this and I think it should be easy enough to explain...somehow...

Answer (score 5):

Here is Niko Tsonev explaining the effects he uses on stage with Steve Wilson.

Here is [his endorsement page at tc electronics](http://www.tcelectronic.com/niko-tsonev/).

If you go to [his website, he provides his email address](http://www.nikotsonev.com). Why not write to him yourself and ask him to explain how he creates these effects?

Comment: Thank you so much for the clip...at least gets me going in the right direction. Write him myself...actually, that's almost where I started out, but I don't think I communicated the effect in question clearly enough, and I don't think he remembered it well enough, perhaps (The show was in 2012). He responded about the use of whammy bars and pedals. True, he used those, but that's on the opposite end of the effect! I hate to pester him further about it.

Comment: @MarkWhiteaker: You can politely respond to him with a link to this question as reference to make it clear to him what you mean.

Comment: Well, I actually had re-responded to Niko Tsonev a while back asking more about the delay. Figuring I had already asked too much and not hearing back as quick as the first try, I chalked up a lost avenue. He just responded back to me with the answer, I believe. He says he used a Line6 particle reverb. The little looking into I have done so far is very promising, and I am very excited! Totally did not expect to hear back. I truly respect the artist, now on a whole new level!